# How to add in the subject tree a new item with Xrm (Dynamics 365)

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, xrm, dynamics-365

I need help to add a new item in the subject tree of dynamics 365, with Xrm and javascript.

Comment: Show us what have you tried..

Comment: this is something new for me, I was looking for examples but I did not find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328006.aspx) is like any other [entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593006.aspx), you can use [web api](http://himbap.com/blog/?p=2035) to create it.

```
function createSubject() {

    var serverURL = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
    var subject = {};
    subject["title"] = "test subject"; 
    subject["featuremask"] = 1;

    //subject["parentsubject@odata.bind"]="/subjects(<GUID without Quotes>)";  //setting existing lookup

    subject["parentsubject"] = {
        "title": "test parent subject",
        "description": "deep insert to add parent before child",
        "featuremask": 1  
    };

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", serverURL + "/api/data/v8.2/subjects", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */ ) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status == 204) {
                var subjectUri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
            } else {
                var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
                alert(error.message);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send(JSON.stringify(subject));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Arun, I use your code, and 
has been successfully execute, I create a lookup field and show me the new items created, but in the subject tree i can't see the new items, how i can delete the new items I created with your code

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaYWw.png in the Subject tree
it does not show me the new items, I can´t delete these items

Comment: Its because of featuremask, https://crmtipoftheday.com/752/hidden-subjects-polluting-the-ui/. we can export/reimport by https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/crm-2011-importing-and-exporting-the-subject-tree/

Comment: is possible delete theses items?

Comment: @GuillermoOvelar "writing code that would iterate over the subject tree and update the featuremask attribute to 1", then it will appear in tree, so you can remove/delete.. Or use console app to make service.Delete sdk call to delete it.

Comment: pd: If you find a solution to delete the added item, please let me know